# Maximum Cash in Ordinary Saving A/c / India

Tags: income-tax, india, banking, financial-literacy

How much cash (maximum) can be kept in Ordinary Saving A/c without the need of filing IT returns?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such specific limit on Savings account.

The requirement for filing IT returns is your taxable income is more 2.5 lacs. There are other clauses, i.e. if you have foreign assets, or getting income from charitable trusts etc.